# Find Serial Buffer Size of Converter

Tags: serial-port, usbserial, javax.comm, termios

I'm using an FTDI USB-to-Serial converter on linux. I'm writing an application that implements the standard functionality of changing settings like baud rate, etc... The only thing that I'm not sure how to get is the buffer size, e.g. if the user wants to know.

For example in the javax.comm SerialPort API there's a method getInputBufferSize(), so I thought there must be a way to check this on the device being used. So if I'm using a USB-to-Serial converter, is it possible to query it for the buffer size? I checked the termios documentation and cannot see such a setting.

Any suggestions on this please?